# Postman assertion twice the identically variable

Tags: variables, postman, assertion

I'm trying to assert the response body. The first assertion where I used to.have is working. The point is that there are multiple variables with the same name in the responsbody. I also need to keep the environmetVariables.

I tried this but it is not working:

```
pm.test("response is ok", function () {
pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});

const body = pm.response.json();
pm.test("VoyageId sent", function() {
pm.expect(body).to.have.property("key", (pm.environment.get("voyageId")));
});

pm.test("VisitId sent", function() {
pm.expect(body).to.have.property("key", (pm.environment.get("visitId")));
});
```

[Printscreen Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYQOo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
const resBody = pm.response.json();

pm.test("Rotatie ...", function () {
    pm.expect(resBody.key).to.eql(pm.environment.get("voyageId"));
});

pm.test("Visist ...", function () {
    pm.expect(resBody.calls[0].key).to.eql(pm.environment.get("visitId"));
});
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response, but need them from the variable.

Comment: @EEO27 Great! Would be much appreciated if you then could accept & upvote my answer. Thank you!